# What is the formula to convert an angle measure in degrees to one between 0 and 360 degrees?

Tags: trigonometry

I know that I can find an equivalent angular measure to $460^\circ$ that's at least $0^\circ$ and less than $360^\circ$ by repeatedly subtracting $360^\circ$ till it's smaller than $360^\circ$, which comes out to be $100^\circ$.

But is there a general formula to do this?  Or is there a formula for this "subtract till smaller than $360^\circ$" in math?

I have tried using modulo but that doesn't make sense … in fact I didn't know what I was doing at the end.

I think I used to know, but now I don't.

Comment: n mod 360 where n is your angle

Comment: If $\theta$ is your angle, use $\theta-360 \lfloor \frac{\theta}{360} \rfloor$.

Comment: Divide by 360, and take the remainder.

Comment: MJD wont further steps be needed

Comment: i found out that beside the first comment there is another way too... `θ-360(Floor(360/θ))`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer copper.hat's equation is precisely what you wrote. Those funny square brackets is the floor function.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: oh i i didn't know that.. those brackets are floor.. Thanks.

Comment: why!? i dont see how this relates to question. As it is pretty basic stuff. But anyways, i was doing something in javascript in which i need to calculate the correct angle. To show.

Comment: write an answer so i can choose it as best jeremyOrCopper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n$ mod $360$ where $n$ is your angle.

In most programming languages, mod is the `%` operator.

Answer (score 6):

use ((n mod 360) + 360) mod 360 if n can be a negative angle.

Comment: or `abs(n mod 360)`

Comment: `abs(n mod 360)` gives you `1` for `-1`. If you need to get `359` instead, use the @aau's solution `((n mod 360) + 360) mod 360`